# The graph of $y=f(x)$ is shown below. Graph the following functions.

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation

[image]

> a. $f(x+1)$
>
> b. $2(f(x-1))$
>
> c. $-f(\frac{x}{2})$
>
> d. $f(2(x-1))$

I know that for a. you have to move the function to the right one unit. I also know how to do c.. However, I have no idea how to do b. and d.. Can someone please explain to me how to do these two questions? Any help and/or solution is appreciated.

Comment: Also—if this is possible—can someone please find a function that looks like the one in this graph? Maybe that might help me understand this question better.

Comment: try graphing $x^4-4x^2$. But before you do that, for b, think about what happens to every x value you plug in, and what happens to the function when you multiply it by a factor of two